# r data.table new columns invisible to set()

Tags: r, data.table

I am confronted with different behavior of set() to "old" and "new" columns in data.table

The situation is so simple, that I probably miss something very basic.

```
library(data.table)

id <- c(1:10) 
x1 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
x2 <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=T)
df<-data.frame(id,x1,x2)
dt<-data.table(df)
setkeyv(dt,c("id"))
```

With "old" columns set works well

```
set(dt,i=(which(x1>5)),j="x2",value=0)
```

When I add a new column, then it is not recognized by set

```
dt[,x4:=x1+x2]
set(dt,i=(which(x4>5)),j="x2",value=0)

Error in which(x4 > 5) : object 'x4' not found
```

Looking at the structure of the dt, it contains the new column, I can work with it, compute mean of it etc.. but the set() does not see it. Why?

Comment: Try `set(dt,i=(which(dt[["x4"]]>5)),j="x2",value=0)`. The first example probably only works because you created `x1` in your global environment

Comment: Yes, this is the "very basic" thing I missed. Thanks.

Comment: [@docendo discimus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus): Yes, it's because `x1` is in your global environment. I would write `dt[x4>5, x2 := 0]` instead, then `x4` is in the scope of `dt`.